# How to install rails bundle in the right place

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I installed `ruby-1.9.3` by my homebrew, so it locate on `/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p286/`.

After installed `Rails` by rvm, I do command `bundle install` but the bundles were all installed to the `/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems` which is an old-version ruby installed with my OS X.

What can I do to let the bundles install in the right place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3--system
```

Comment: $ rvm use 1.9.3(no space)--system, It works! Although i already reinstall my ruby by rvm

Answer (score 1):

Use either [rvm](https://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](http://rbenv.org/) to manage different versions of ruby. You could also consider [JewelryBox](http://jewelrybox.unfiniti.com/), which does pretty much the same thing, but with a prettier GUI.

Comment: Since my ruby was installed by homebrew, it won't find my ruby path when i click `rvm use 1.9.3` to console. I wonder maybe there is a config file or a env variable to index the gem path